# Find if non-intersecting path exists between source and destination

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

A matrix of dimension `m*n` is given. It has cells that represent the following - `.` denotes a road cell; `#` denotes a block cell; `a` and `b` are two different starting points with `A` and `B` as their respective destinations. One can traverse either up, down, right or left.

Expectation is to return a boolean output if there exists a path from `a` to `A` and `b` to `B` such that the paths don't intersect at any point

Example 1:

```
a.b 
..# 
A.B
```

Output: `true`

Example 2:

```
a.b
### 
A.B
```

Output: `false`

I am aware of the DFS approach when there is only a single source and destination (this can also be extended for 2 sources/destinations). But this question poses a constraint that the two paths should be non-intersecting - this confuses me on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Something to consider. 1) Find all non-cyclical paths from A to a. 2) Find all non-cyclical paths from B to b. 3) For each path Aa, determine if there is a path Bb that does not intersect. This is essentially the brute-force solution. Not necessarily the fastest, but it will work and solving it will perhaps point you at a more performant solution.

Comment: @JimMischel - am I correct in assuming that this brute force approach would take exponential time?

Comment: Yes, the complexity is O(|V|!), where V is the number of vertices. See https://www.baeldung.com/cs/simple-paths-between-two-vertices.